# Change from most recent submit time on same day changes MYSQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
`pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Delivery_Date` date NOT NULL,
`Hour_Ending` time NOT NULL,
`Resource_Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
`Eff_HASL` float DEFAULT NULL,
`Submit_Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)
);

INSERT INTO `foo` (`pk`,`id`,`Delivery_Date`,`Hour_Ending`,`Resource_Name`,`eff_hasl`,`Submit_Time`) VALUES 
(1,'2435672','2012-01-25','09:00:00','BASTEN_1',0,'2012-01-18 08:33:52'),
(2,'2435672','2012-01-25','09:00:00','BASTEN_1',0,'2012-01-19 07:47:33'),
(11,'2435672','2012-01-25','09:00:00','BASTEN_1',269,'2012-01-25 05:50:05'),

(3,'2435672','2012-01-26','09:00:00','BASTEN_2',111,'2012-01-18 08:33:52'),
(4,'2435672','2012-01-26','09:00:00','BASTEN_2',0,'2012-01-24 07:47:33'),
(5,'2435672','2012-01-26','09:00:00','BASTEN_2',269,'2012-01-25 05:45:05'),
(6,'2435672','2012-01-26','09:00:00','BASTEN_2',269,'2012-01-26 05:50:05'),

(7,'2435672','2012-01-27','09:00:00','BASTEN_3',111,'2012-01-18 08:33:52'),
(8,'2435672','2012-01-27','09:00:00','BASTEN_3',0,'2012-01-24 07:47:33'),
(9,'2435672','2012-01-27','09:00:00','BASTEN_3',269,'2012-01-27 05:45:05'),
(10,'2435672','2012-01-27','09:00:00','BASTEN_3',500,'2012-01-27 05:50:05');

SELECT * FROM foo;
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+
| pk | ID      | Delivery_Date | Hour_Ending | Resource_Name | Eff_HASL | Submit_Time         |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2435672 | 2012-01-25    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_1      |        0 | 2012-01-18 08:33:52 |
|  2 | 2435672 | 2012-01-25    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_1      |        0 | 2012-01-19 07:47:33 |
|  3 | 2435672 | 2012-01-26    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_2      |      111 | 2012-01-18 08:33:52 |
|  4 | 2435672 | 2012-01-26    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_2      |        0 | 2012-01-24 07:47:33 |
|  5 | 2435672 | 2012-01-26    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_2      |      269 | 2012-01-25 05:45:05 |
|  6 | 2435672 | 2012-01-26    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_2      |      269 | 2012-01-26 05:50:05 |
|  7 | 2435672 | 2012-01-27    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_3      |      111 | 2012-01-18 08:33:52 |
|  8 | 2435672 | 2012-01-27    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_3      |        0 | 2012-01-24 07:47:33 |
|  9 | 2435672 | 2012-01-27    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_3      |      269 | 2012-01-27 05:45:05 |
| 10 | 2435672 | 2012-01-27    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_3      |      500 | 2012-01-27 05:50:05 |
| 11 | 2435672 | 2012-01-25    | 09:00:00    | BASTEN_1      |      269 | 2012-01-25 05:50:05 |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+
```

I have a table with a series of updates for a specific hour which is noted by Delivery_Date and hour_ending (we'll call operating hour).  The Submit_Time is when the update happened.  The updates can start 14 day prior to the operating hour.

An update can happen once 14 days ago and never be changed or they can be changed every hour up until the operating hour.  Most of the time the eff_hasl is changed a couple of times, but rarely are these changes made the same day as the operating hour.

My query is attempting to catch the changes that happen the same day as the operating hour by using the Delivery_Date = date(Submit_Time) clause. I can't figure out how to set an initial state to compare against.  This query only looks at the same day submissions, but can't compare against the most recent submit if there is a same day submission.  I only care if the eff_hasl changes.

I'm looking for a delta for each resource for each delivery_date for each hour_ending for the whole year.  If the resource doesn't have a same day submit the delta should = 0, if they do it should compare the list of entries on the same day submit and the last previous submit before that day.  So it should come out something like:

BASTEN_1 delta for 2012-01-25 09:00:00 = 269 something like:

'2012-01-25','09:00:00','BASTEN_1', 269

BASTEN_2 delta for 2012-01-26 09:00:00 = 0 something like

'2012-01-26','09:00:00','BASTEN_2', 0

BASTEN_3 = 500 ...

```
select Delivery_Date, Hour_Ending, Resource_Name, min(eff_hasl)-max(eff_hasl) delta
from foo 
where Delivery_Date = date(Submit_Time)
group by Resource_Name, date(Delivery_Date), hour(hour_ending) having delta <> 0;
```

I am thinking there needs to be some sort of sub query?  I want to include the most recent submittal prior to date(operating hour) to compare against in the list.  something like:

```
select a.Delivery_Date, a.Hour_Ending, a.Resource_Name, min(b.eff_hasl)-max(a.eff_hasl) delta
from foo as a
inner join (SELECT Resource_Name, Delivery_Date, Hour_Ending, submit_time, 
    eff_hasl  
    FROM foo
    where date(submit_time) < Delivery_date
    GROUP BY resource_name, delivery_date, Hour_Ending
    order by Submit_Time desc
    limit 1
) as b
ON      (b.resource_name = a.resource_name AND b.delivery_date = 
         a.delivery_date AND b.hour_ending = a.hour_ending)
where a.Delivery_Date = date(a.Submit_Time)
group by a.Resource_Name, date(a.Delivery_Date), hour(a.hour_ending) having delta <> 0;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler if  `Delivery_Date` and `Hour_Ending` were a single entity called, say, operating_hour

Comment: I'm not sure.  Would it?

Comment: Yep. In general, dates and times should always be stored as a single entity unless you have a very specific reason for not doing so.